# mysql select from 3 different tables

Tags: mysql

I am trying to select from three different tables and order by the date columns:

```
table_1:
date_1, col_1a, col_1b, col_1c, col_1d, col_1e

table_2:
date_2, col_2a, col_2b, col_2c

table_3:
date_3, col_3a, col_3b, col_3c, col_3d
```

I am trying to achieve something like:

```
select * from table_1, table_2, table_3 order by (date) desc
```

I want the output to be ordered by the most recent date. Is this possible?

Many thanks,

Neil.

Comment: Look up using JOIN on primary and foreign key between tables

Comment: Give us the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_1, 2, 3\G` - that way we can determine your `JOIN` conditions.

Comment: Certainly it is possible.  However, It is not possible to answer your question with certainty given the lack of information you provided in your question.  Are these tables related in any way?  If so how?  If not what is the nature of the individual columns?  You have 2 tables with 5 columns and 1 table with 4.  Why is that?

Comment: Hello, thank you. It is a "union all" that I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query does a cross join of the 3 tables which produces the cartesian product of the 3 tables which is not what you want (I think).
I suspect you want `UNION` or `UNION ALL`:

```
select 'table_1' fromtable, date_1 date, col_1a cola, col_1b colb, col_1c colc, col_1d cold, col_1e cole from table_1
union all
select 'table_2', date_2, col_2a, col_2b, col_2c, null, null from table_2
union all
select 'table_3', date_3, col_3a, col_3b, col_3c, col_3d, null from table_3
order by date
```

For this code to work the corresponding columns in all 3 tables must have the same data type.

Comment: Thanks. This is the kind of output I want. Is it also possible to identify the table name in the output?

Comment: Do you want in each row something like table_1 or table_2 or table_3?

Comment: Yes. In order to identify the table.

Comment: Hello, on each of the select statements, how would I "order by date_1 desc limit 1", "order by date_2 desc limit 1", "order by date_3 desc limit 1" in order to just have one row output from each of the 3 tables? Thank you.

Comment: Check this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jLXMmT287DbuU8tEJGjC4j/1

Answer (score 0):

If the tables share a common column, that is, `table_1.date = table_2.date`, you can do a `join`

```
SELECT * FROM table_1
    LEFT JOIN (t2 CROSS JOIN t3)
                 ON (table_2.date = table_1.date AND table_3.date = table_1.date)
```

If the three tables are completely distinct from each other, then no, you cannot display them in one `SELECT`.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. It is a "union all" I am looking for.

Comment: You would be correct.  I will update my answer to be correct.